# How to use case clause in where condition using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am going to filter with one query in SQL Server. but I am getting error some thing like this

> **Incorrect syntax near '='**.

I have one table. In this table store 2 column 1 is socialtype and 2 is ISFUser like this. I want to filter some on this 2 column.my filter param is All,Instagram,ISFUser. so i need to All select then want to all data. then after I select Instagram only then get InstagramUsers. like this.

Here This is my query.

```
declare @Filter nvarchar(max) = 'Instagram'
select * from Users 
where IsDeleted = 0 and @Filter = 
case 
when @Filter = 'Instagram' then socialtype 
when @Filter = 'ISFUser' then (ISFUser = 1)
ELSE  @Filter = 'ALL'  then (1 = 1)
END
```

This is my query I want to apply filter but how can do I have no idea. I am getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could expand your condition to:

```
declare @Filter nvarchar(max) = 'Instagram';

select * 
from Users 
where IsDeleted = 0 
  and (
        (@Filter = 'Instagram' and socialtype = 'Instagram')
        OR
        (@Filter = 'ISFUser' AND IFUser = 1)
        OR 
        @Filter = 'ALL'
      );
```

Comment: Thank you so much i want like this.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're trying to do is the following:

```
select
    *
from
    Users 
where
    IsDeleted = 0 and (
        @Filter = 'ALL' or
        @Filter = 'ISFUser' and ISFUser = 1 or
        @Filter = 'Instagram' and socialtype = 'Instagram'
    )
```